# Autobahn cannot import autobahn.wamp.router

Tags: python, python-2.6, autobahn, crossbar

I'm getting an import error when running `crossbar start`:

```
2016-05-19 15:39:52+0300 [Controller   6020] ImportError: No module named autobahn.wamp.router
```

I've found the source for the router module [here](http://autobahn.ws/python/_modules/autobahn/wamp/router.html) but it seems to be missing from my library (I'm running version 0.14.0).

Am I missing something?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After trying multiple autobahn versions, v0.8.3 seems to do the trick. It looks like the router module has been deprecated at some point after this version.